# speech to text training for impaired voice

Tags: speech-to-text

I want to train and use an ML based personal voice to text converter for a highly impaired voice, for a small set of 300-400 words. This is to be used for people with voice impairment. But cannot be generic because each person will have a unique voice input for words, depending on their type of impairment.

Wanted to know if there are any ML engines which allow for such a training. If not, what is the best approach to go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most of the speech recognition engines support training (wav2letter, deepspeech, espnet, kaldi, etc), you just need to feed in the data. The only issue is that you need a lot of data to train reliably (1000 of samples for each word). You can check Google Commands dataset for example of how to train from scratch.

Since the training dataset will be pretty small for your case and will consist of just a few samples, you can probably start with existing pretrained model and finetune it on your samples to get best accuracy. You need to look on "few short learning" setups.

You can probably look on wav2vec 2.0 pretrained model, it should be effective for such learning. You can find examples and commands for fine-tuning and inference [here](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/tree/master/examples/wav2vec).

You can also try fine-tuning Japser models in [Google Commands for NVIDIA NEMO](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/nemo/developer_guide/en/v0.11.0/speech_command/tutorial.html#fine-tuning). It might be a little less effective but could still work and should be easier to setup.

Answer (score 0):

I highely recommend watching the youtube original series "The age of AI"'s First season, episode two.

Basically, google already done this for people who can't really form normal words with impared voice. It is very interesting and speaks a little bit about how they done and doing that with ML technologies.

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5aZjsWM2wo)

Comment: Thanks. Euphonia is still in research phase. My target is to help people train a personal engine for a bare basic transcribing of a small set of words of common use. If they can do for just 50 words, will be a great help instead of waiting for the perfect transcriber. All of this assuming that the most needy will spend time to train.